# How do I convert a byte slice of unknown size to a byte array?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I need to unmarshal some data, and in one case, the marshaled data represents a map with a byte array as a key.

Slices are not allowed as map keys, however arrays are. But the problem here is that arrays can't be created with a non-constant size as far as I can tell.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func getHashable(value interface{}) interface{} {
    rfl := reflect.ValueOf(value)
    if rfl.Kind() == reflect.Slice && rfl.Type().Elem().Kind() == reflect.Uint8 {
        slice, ok := value.([]uint8)
        if !ok {
            panic(fmt.Errorf("Could not coerce to []uint8"))
        }
        var arr [len(slice)]uint8 // This fails
        copy(arr, slice)
        value = arr
    }
    return value
}

func unmarshalMap(serialized []byte) map[interface{}]interface{} {
    result := make(map[interface{}]interface{})
    for len(serialized) > 0 {
        var value interface{}
        key, bytesConsumed := deserializeValue(serialized)
        serialized = serialized[bytesConsumed:]
        value, bytesConsumed = deserializeValue(serialized)
        serialized = serialized[bytesConsumed:]
        result[getHashable(key)] = value
    }
}
```

If deserializeValue() returns a []byte, then it can't be stored as a key in the result map. An array would work, but I can't create an array because I don't know what size I'll need until runtime, and it only allows compile time constants.

A simplified version https://play.golang.org/p/wkYGs3S-uSD fails with the error

```
./prog.go:15:12: non-constant array bound len(slice)
```

How can I use an array of bytes that I've unmarshaled as a key in a map in Go?

Comment: But the map key is a byte array, and users of this library need to know it's a byte array when they get their result. And blindly converting a byte array to a string will create invalid characters.

Comment: Your requirements are unclear. If you have a literal byte array, just use that as your key. If you have something else (which it sounds like), then you can't preserve the original type anyway, so it doesn't seem like a loss.

Comment: I'm writing an unmarshaler, and need to pass the unmarshaled data back to the user. If the marshaled data was {[0x81, 0xff, 0x41, 0x11] = true}, then I need the unmarshaled result to also be in the same structure. In this case, the byte array [81 ff 41 11] needs to be the key in the map I'm returning from the unmarshal function.

Comment: Are you (un)marshaling to a standard format, or creating your own?

Comment: In any case, I don't believe that such keys can be expressed using standard Go types. You'll need to come up with a creative work-around. Or if you control the format, maybe you can come up with a more Go-friendly format.

Comment: Doesn't matter. When unmarshalling data, the idea is to preserve types, and converting to string loses that information. Creating a custom string type to differentiate "real" strings from "actually a byte array" strings is a hack that just adds extra headaches for the end user, having to keep checking for that type and manually convert on every use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While use a `string` is clearly the better way, if the code you don't control uses a byte array as key, here is how you can turn the byte slice into an array as an interface using reflect.

```
varr := reflect.New(reflect.ArrayOf(len(slice), reflect.TypeOf(uint8(0))))
reflect.Copy(varr.Elem(), reflect.ValueOf(slice))

return varr.Elem().Interface()
```

Please consider other options before using this.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/CXsxZwgjiRR

Comment: Oh wow that's a beautiful monstrosity! OK, if that's the only way I can unmarshal a map key that turns out to be a byte array, I'll have to think about whether to just say "unsupported"...

Comment: Note that the fundamental problem is that the map's keys have to implement `==` / `!=`.  Arrays do, but arrays have compile-time-fixed-sizes. This "beautiful monstrosity" (I like that term!) gives you an interface object that implements the equality comparisons, along with runtime-created, runtime-blessed pseudo-arrays that read back as arrays when going through the `reflect` code (so in that sense they *are* arrays) that nonethless have no compile-time existence (so in that sense they *aren't* arrays).

Comment: @torek you are absolutely right. But I would like to add is while this is awkward to use (the user may have a hard coded array as a key though), it is unlikely to shoot yourself in feet when use. It is not unsafe, just bad code.

Answer (score 3):

Use `string` instead of a fixed size array of bytes. A string can hold an arbitrary sequence of bytes.

```
func getHashable(value interface{}) interface{} {
    rfl := reflect.ValueOf(value)
    if rfl.Kind() == reflect.Slice && rfl.Type().Elem().Kind() == reflect.Uint8 {
        value = string(rfl.Bytes())
    }
    return value
}
```

If you are only need to handle `[]byte` and not named types for `[]byte`, use type assertions instead of reflection:

```
func getHashable(value interface{}) interface{} {
    switch value := value.(type) {
    case []byte:
         return string(value)
    default:
         return value
    }
}
```

If the user of the map needs to distinguish string keys from keys created form []byte, define a string type to distinguish those values:

```
type convertedSlice string
```

Replace use of `string()` conversion in the code above with `convertedSlice()`.

The application can check for converted keys with:

```
_, ok := key.(convertedSlice) // ok is true if key is converted slice.
```

and convert the keys back to []byte with:

```
cv, ok := key.(convertedSice)
if ok {
   key = []byte(cv)
}
```

Comment: This won't preserve the type. Unmarshaling a byte array needs to result in an actual byte array, not a string.

Comment: @Karl It's unclear from the comment how the values relate to unmarshalling.  Edit the question to show the unmarshalling scenario.